# How to penalize coefficient of some features in a model?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, model

I am building a logistic regression model for classification purposes -- I have 8 features - a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4.
I want to build a model such that I should be able to penalize the coefficients of some of these features. For example, say no penalty for a1, a2, a3, a4 and l2 penalty for b1, b2, b3, b4.

I am looking for both a theoretical solution and probably some direction to implement it in Python

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking the general theoretical question about applying this kind of penalty in a flexible manner or are you looking for explicit Python solutions?  (The former is on topic here but the latter is not.)

Comment: I am asking both.

Comment: I see someone has already voted to close your question, probably under the assumption you are focusing on the code.  You can stave off additional close votes by editing this post to emphasize the statistical aspect of the question.